# Modify Facebook app permission to resubmit the app

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-apps

We had created one facebook app for allowing user to do signup / login with facebook.

Recently due to some changes in facebook privacy we got a notification from facebook saying we need to resubmit the app for the permission which require review from facebook. and we need to re-submit this app before 1st Aug. 2018. in order to continue with required permission.

We have reviewed permission which was requested initially but we found that there is only one permission which requires facebook review and we actually dont need this permission. Is there any way to remove that permission from the list and resubmit the app? or if we dont resubmit the app, facebook will remove that specific permission from the app and will continue with other default permission? or will it deactivate entire facebook app?

We prefer to resubmit app by removing that extra permission, we have found the way to add new permission in the app but not how to remove any permission

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your app will simply not be able to ask users for un-reviewed permissions - as long as it doesn’t actively do so, there should be no problem at all. Re-submitting for review does not make sense in this case - you did not _add_ anything new, and _removal_ of stuff doesn’t require any “review”.

Comment: @Nikita Shah And, what happened? Did your app continue to work after the deadline (for the no longer used permission) passed? If so, please consider answering your own question. This way any user can upvote the answer and the question is clearly marked as "answered" (e.g. when doing a search with "answers:1").

Comment: Sorry guys but now not working anymore on this project