# How to resubmit live FB App after permission removal

Tags: facebook

For quite some time now, I have a Facebook app registered, reviewed and live.
Recently FB decided to "proactively" do an App Review, as I didn't take any (FB requested) action myself.
After completion of this review, I went to

1. developer.facebook.com
2. chose the app in question
3. clicked "App Review", "Current Request"

and read `Status: Action required: Review and address feedback, and resubmit`

Mmmh. Surely something to do on my side ...

Looking at the section "Requested Permissions and Features" I noticed my app was requesting a bunch of permissions (cf. 1st screenshot) --- none needed (for a long time).
Thus I deleted all of the listed permissions by clicking on the trash icon, expecting the button labeled "Submit for Review" to turn clickable. Alas, the button stayed disabled (cf. 2nd screenshot)

My questions are:

1. What do I need to do to get my app into review, again? (i.e. being nice and following FB's advice "Review and address feedback, and resubmit")
2. Am I misunderstanding the whole situation and deleting the permissions and just waiting for FB's deadline is the right thing to do? If so, is there any "official FB doc" stating this?

PS: I've tried hard to make the mentioned review button clickable (looking around for other infos FB might want to know from me, toggling the app status, using different browsers, manipulating the button's html, googling) . To no avail.

PPS: Some of this overlaps with [Modify Facebook app permission to resubmit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167936/) but the answer (actually only a comment without any authoritative reference) doesn't settle things for me.

[image: Example of a permission prior to deletion]

[image: Situation showing disabled review button]

Comment: Well if your app is not using any permissions or features that require review, then there simply isn’t anything to submit …

Comment: @misorude You may be right: But the phrase "Action required: Review and address feedback, and resubmit" is then imho misleading, as it implies a resubmission is a requirement (i.e. can not be circumvented by deleting previously requested permissions). Do you have any references for your claim?

Comment: The phrasing is based on the assumption that your app is actually still using those permissions; but if in your case they are only listed because you asked for them at some point in the past, maybe only during testing, but are not actively asking for them any more, then there’s nothing to review in that regard.

Comment: You are probably right; thanks for taking away my doubts. Please make your comment an answer; I will mark it as such, if the app is still "live" after the deadline has passed :-).

Comment: The app will stay “live” no matter what, live/dev mode is not dependent on review. Your app would just not be able to ask normal users for any permissions any more, that have not been reviewed.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. There is no option for resubmit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is not using any permissions or features that require review, then there simply isn’t anything to submit.

> But the phrase "Action required: Review and address feedback, and resubmit" is then imho misleading

That phrasing is based on the assumption that your app is actually still using those permissions, which is likely the case for the majority of affected apps.
But if in your case they are only listed because you asked for them at some point in the past, maybe only during testing, but are not actively asking for them any more, then there’s nothing to review in that regard.